# How to sync with server data by AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Angular has two ways data binding which is cool, so I just wonder if it could be sync in Server-Client binding? For example, usually we would request data by $http

```
$http.get(apiURL)
    .then(function(rsp){
      console.log('getRsp', rsp);
    });
```

I hope it could send request automatically once server side (inside database for example) changes.

In tranditionally, we can use timeout, but it is kind old way, and watsting resource. What if we can listen the server change? But how?!

Comment: Use socket, what server do you have on backend ? NodeJS ? IIS ? Other ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217520/angular-with-socket-io-backend-php

Comment: Yeah, you need sockets. Check out http://socket.io/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achiece this by using socket.io. Both on server and client side. By using timeout all of the clients will repeatedly keep on calling the server even if there is no update. With sockets you can keep a channel open between server and client. The server will only notify the client whenever there is a change in the data.

You can find a lot tutorials for sockets on the internet.